# Error getting month while using Calendar object

Tags: java

I'm using Calendar API to manipulate date. Here is snippet of code i'm trying.

```
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse("05/10/2013");
              Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
              cal.setTime(date);
              int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Here i should get month as 9(Oct) but its returning 0(Jan).Even if I change date it still returns 0(Jan). 
        Why this is happening? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use *`MM` instead of `mm`*  small `m` gives *Minute in hour* and *to get Month* use capital `M`

```
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("05/10/2013");
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
System.out.println("" + month);
```

*Output:*

```
9
```

[Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[image]

Comment: -1 OP is trying to get month.As per question OP should get 9 but its getting 0.In your way it will get 1;

Comment: great @Tarsem.I was really confused before. Got it now.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

sue `MM` instead of `mm` in the given date format. `M` specifies month while `m` specifies minute according to [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
    Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("05/10/2013")
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
              cal.setTime(date);
              int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // add +1 for correct month(10) otherwise it will be 9
```